# How to do conference call in efficient way using Kurento Media Server

Tags: java, call, kurento, conference, fiware-kurento

I want a suggestion to implement the conference call in kurento media server

I have tried to use composite element but it sends a grid of a video combined in one its working fine but i want to add a functionality for the user that if user tap a particular video it should be become bigger which cannot be done in compiste because of its sending only one combined video stream

Needed suggestion what can i use in kurento for adding this functionality
Thanks